# Use one foreach loop instead of two

Tags: php, arrays, optimization

I have one array

```
$array = array(0=>array('id'=>1 ,'va'=>2),1=>array('id'=>3,'va'=>4));
```

With the help of two foreach() loop i can use it.

```
    foreach($array as $temp)
    {
       foreach($temp as $key=>$val)
       {
           echo $key.'=>'.$val;
       }
    }
```

As array has more than 5 lacs record. this solution is not feasible for me.
Keys are dynamic so i can not put keys as static inside first for each loop.
I tried following code but till now did not get any solution.

```
function myfunction($value,$key)
{
    foreach($value as $k=>$a)
    {
        echo $k.'=>'.$a;
    }
}
$array = array(0=>array('id'=>1,'va'=>2),1=>array('id'=>2,'va'=>2));
array_walk($array,"myfunction");
```

And this one also

```
$keys = Array_keys($array['0']);
for($i=0;$<=count($array);$i++) 
{
    for($j=0;$j<count($keys);$j++)
    {
        echo $keys[$j].'=>'.$array[$i][$keys];
    }
}
```

I want to make this code as optmize as possible.

Comment: you can't avoid using 2x `foreach()` or `array_walk()`, except that `array_walk()` is slower than `foreach()`. also, don't use `count()` in loops because each iteration will count the number of elements; make a variable `$count = count($array)` and use the variable instead

Comment: as I understood his question he says the array can be 5 levels deep so that would make it 5x foreach

Comment: Thanks for reply.No it will be only two level deep but array has 5 lacs record so i want it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: for information, I understand that a `lac` is 'one hundred thousand' or  1.0e5? So, the array has, approximately, `half a million entries` (500,000)?

Comment: yeah that array has that many entries in it,

Comment: @RyanVincent your code is displaying only 'id' i need to dispaly all the keys inside that array.

Comment: The `nested foreach loops` take about about 0.6 of one second to process one hundred thousand rows (1.0e5) on my dual 'hamster' pc. The loop overhead is about 0.35. It is the quickest method of the ones suggested

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks mate.